# How to plot multiple graphs in Matplotlib from the numpy datasets I am working on?

Tags: numpy, matplotlib, array-broadcasting

I am new to programming, and I'm having difficulty plotting multiple graphs. What I am trying to get is a graph containing values of K along the Y-axis plotted against values of Dk. I need this graph to contain all the K=f(Dk) for each temperature Tcwin in range (10,40,1)
While the code seems to be working well and I have obtained the data I was trying to calculate, I can't seem to plot them. Any help would be appreciated.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
A=3000
d_in=20
CF=0.85
w=2.26
Tcwin=12
Dk=np.arange(27.418,301.598,27.418)
dk=(Dk*1000/(A*3.600))
cp=4.19
Gw=13000
e=2.718281828
f_velocity=w*1.1/(20**0.25)
for Tcwin in range(10,40,1):
    while Tcwin<35:
        print(Tcwin)
        f_w=0.12*CF*(1+0.15*Tcwin)
        Ф_в=f_velocity**f_w
        K=CF*4070*((1.1*w/(d_in**0.25))**(0.12*CF*(1+0.15*Tcwin)))*(1-(((35-Tcwin)**2)*(0.52-0.0072*dk)*(CF**0.5))/1000)
        n=(K*A)/(cp*Gw*1000)
        Tcwout_theor=Tcwin+(Dk*2225/(cp*Gw))
        Subcooling_theor=(Tcwout_theor-Tcwin)/(e**(K*A/(cp*(Gw*1000/3600)*1000)))
        TR_theor=Tcwout_theor-Tcwin
        Tsat_theor=Tcwout_theor+Subcooling_theor
        print(K)
        print(Tcwout_theor)
        print(Subcooling_theor)
        print(Tsat_theor)
        Tcwin+=1
    else:
        print('Loop done')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for? plotting after each run:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
A=3000
d_in=20
CF=0.85
w=2.26
Tcwin=12
Dk=np.arange(27.418,301.598,27.418)
dk=(Dk*1000/(A*3.600))
cp=4.19
Gw=13000
e=2.718281828
f_velocity=w*1.1/(20**0.25)
for Tcwin in range(10,40,1):
    while Tcwin<35:
        print(Tcwin)
        f_w=0.12*CF*(1+0.15*Tcwin)
        Ф_в=f_velocity**f_w
        K=CF*4070*((1.1*w/(d_in**0.25))**(0.12*CF*(1+0.15*Tcwin)))*(1-(((35-Tcwin)**2)*(0.52-0.0072*dk)*(CF**0.5))/1000)
        n=(K*A)/(cp*Gw*1000)
        Tcwout_theor=Tcwin+(Dk*2225/(cp*Gw))
        Subcooling_theor=(Tcwout_theor-Tcwin)/(e**(K*A/(cp*(Gw*1000/3600)*1000)))
        TR_theor=Tcwout_theor-Tcwin
        Tsat_theor=Tcwout_theor+Subcooling_theor
        print(K)
        print(Tcwout_theor)
        print(Subcooling_theor)
        print(Tsat_theor)
        Tcwin+=1
        plt.plot(K,dk) #---------------> this is the code for plotting 
        
    else:
        print('Loop done')
```

Comment: not really. I need all these lines plotted on one plot. Your code will reslt in a multitude of plots.

Comment: I see, I've update the code accordingly, let me know if this is what you wanted. Note: the plot will show at the end of the run!

Comment: thanks a lot! Now it seems to work according to what I born in mind.

Comment: Glad to be of help. you may want then go ahead and accept the answer.